# Replacing bulb in surface mount light

Tags: light-fixture

I am struggling to remove the light diffuser of this surface mount light so that I can replace bulbs. Any help is hugely appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The diffuser is normally screwed on.  Looking upwards, hold the edges and try turning clockwise.

Comment: FYI, "flush mount" means that the fixture is below the surface, such as with recessed cans. This is a surface-mount fixture. That's a common misconception perpetuated even by the likes of Lowes.

Answer (score 1):

I would try turning the black ring anti-clockwise - it may be threaded or could need turning with sufficient force to pass the clips.

Also try gently pulling down on the black ring as it may just have clips that work vertically so it does not need to be rotated.